# React escaping from mouse down event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react app i have table in which i have this event which handles column resize by user.

```
handleMouseDown(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let leftCol = e.target.parentElement
        let rightCol = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling
        let leftColOffset = leftCol.offsetWidth - e.pageX
        let rightColOffset = rightCol.offsetWidth + e.pageX
        onmousemove = (event) => {
            leftCol.style.width = leftColOffset + event.pageX + 'px';
            rightCol.style.width = rightColOffset - event.pageX + 'px';
            onmouseup = () => {
                onmousemove = null
            }
        }
        onmouseup = () => {
            //here i need somenthing that would break me out of parent function
        }
    }
```

This event is triggered by mouseDown on drag handle like this

```
<div class="resizeGrip" onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}></div>
```

My question is: How do i break out of handleMouseDown function? Because it stays always active after first mousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thing you are passing event as e to the function, so you have to do `e.preventDefault()` instead of `event.preventDefault`. Here your mousedown event is represented by `e`

Secondly, there is no need to listen to onMouseUp inside onMouseMove, following code should help you -

```
handleMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let leftCol = e.target.parentElement
    let rightCol = e.target.parentElement.nextSibling
    let leftColOffset = leftCol.offsetWidth - e.pageX
    let rightColOffset = rightCol.offsetWidth + e.pageX
    onmousemove = (event) => {
        leftCol.style.width = leftColOffset + event.pageX + 'px';
        rightCol.style.width = rightColOffset - event.pageX + 'px';
    }
    onmouseup = () => {
        onmousemove = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank thats it :)